# Collect customer information upon registration

Tags: magento-1.8, database, php-5.4

So in order to help prevent fraud on my website, I want to setup a table that collects information about a person when they register on my site. Information such as Real IP address, Proxy IP address, referer URL, cookies, browser information (type of browser, version, plugins, fonts), flash hash, maybe a generated salted hash from their password input.

I've searched around and can't find any significantly helpful articles on created a script for this. I imagine I'd need to create the table in mysql, and then reference the table via a custom PHP doc. However, I need help on the script for collecting such information to begin with. Any help is greatly appreciated!

The only page I could find similar to this was http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-track-visitors-information/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab all the customer details by using this event: `customer_register_success`

This observer will give you the customer data.

Your observer class

```
<?php
class NameSpace_ModuleName_Model_Observer
{
    public function getCustomerData(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
       $customer      = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
       //do your other stuff
    }
}
```

Now you can get any info of customer which is stored in magento database.

```
$customer->getPrefix();
$customer->getName(); // Full Name
$customer->getFirstname(); // First Name
$customer->getMiddlename(); // Middle Name
$customer->getLastname(); // Last Name
$customer->getSuffix();

// All other customer data
$customer->getWebsiteId(); // ID
$customer->getEntityId(); // ID
$customer->getEntityTypeId(); // ID
$customer->getAttributeSetId(); // ID
$customer->getEmail();
$customer->getGroupId(); // ID
$customer->getStoreId(); // ID
$customer->getCreatedAt(); // yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss+01:00
$customer->getUpdatedAt(); // yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
$customer->getIsActive(); // 1
$customer->getDisableAutoGroupChange();
$customer->getTaxvat();
$customer->getPasswordHash();
$customer->getCreatedIn(); // Admin
$customer->getGender(); // ID
$customer->getDefaultBilling(); // ID
$customer->getDefaultShipping(); // ID
$customer->getDob(); // yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
$customer->getTaxClassId(); // ID
```

Now, to get other stuff like browser, fonts etc, you can use `$visitorData = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getVisitorData();` and fetch to your own table as you require.

**Assumption**

1. You already know how to use observer in Magento. This requires you to create a simple extension, which observes customer's registration behaviour.
2. You also need to create your own table, [learn here](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/)

Good luck.

Comment: So essentially, I need to create a new module using the `customer_register_success` event, with an observer class that includes `$visitorData = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getVisitorData();` along with any other information I want to grab that's already stored in the database once registered.  Then fetch it to a new table, where I can call it in a new file (or somewhere in the admin panel if needed).

Comment: You got it all correct Taskle. Good luck.